# Как сделать мьютекс с приоритетами или RW-lock с эксклюзивным чтением?

Tags: алгоритм, boost, c++

Доброго времени суток!

Есть некоторая структура данных, к которой обращается малое число поставщиков данных и в несколько раз больше число потребителей. И поставщик данных, и потребитель требует эксклюзивной блокировки для своей работы, но если использовать обычный mutex, то в результате получается перекос в сторону потребителей, и поставщики данных начинают терять производительность.

Фактически необходимо три уровня приоритетов: shared - read-only операции, которые могут выполняться реально одновременно, не мешая друг другу; consume-exclusive - низкопроиоритетные операции, требующие эксклюзивной блокировки; produce-exclusive - высокоприоритетные операции, требующие эксклюзивной блокировки.
В принципе shared можно даже не выделять, а использовать consume-exclusive уровень для этих задач, так как они очень маленькие по ресурсоемкости (много меньше, чем другие операции).

Первой мыслью было взять boost::shared_mutex и внутри shared-блокировки использовать обычный mutex для разделения читателей, но тогда получится, что если на этом мутексе заблокируется читатель, и в этот момент придет писатель и начнет ждать уникальную блокировку, то вначале все равно отработает читатель, и только после того, как он освободит shared-блокировку, писатель сможет приступить к работе.

Как-либо менять приоритеты потоков или воздействовать на планировщика ОС нельзя, так как эти потоки еще много другой работы выполняют, и будет очень плохо, если у них будут как-то меняться приоритеты.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать подобную функциональность?

Comment: А зачем вам имплементировать самому? Есть же в [последнем boost'е](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks) (`unique_lock`, `shared_lock`).

Comment: Хороший вопрос (+1). 

--

@alglu65, если правильно понял, Вы хотите приоритетный RW-lock. 

Т.е. если появился более приоритетный запрос, то он блокирует исполнение новых менее приоритетных, но дожидается, пока уже получившие блокировку менее приоритетные запросы (много, это если они shared) ее не отдадут?

--

На ум приходит приоритетная очередь для выполнения запросов к этому RW-mutex (со своими mutex + cond). Да, вокруг стандартных pthread lock-unlock придется делать wrappers (и наверное структуры mutex-ов тоже совмещать со своими данными).

--

Что же касается boost -- вообще дело Ваше.

Comment: @avp: А вот [примерная имплементация](http://stackoverflow.com/a/244376/276994) с обсуждением.

Comment: @VladD, глубоко не вникал, а идея "псевдолока" довольно интересная. 

Заметили, во всех вызовах mutex разблокируется  перед return.

Comment: @avp: Угу. Он используется для эксклюзивного доступа к структуре, а не для собственно ожидания. Ну и `pthread_cond_wait`/`pthread_cond_signal` требует запуска из-под `lock`'а.

Comment: Да. 

Думаю, это подходящая идея для ТС. Только ему (IMHO) лучше будет использовать один mutex для всех блокировок (не делить на read/write/high-priority/... и вместо `pthread_cond_signal` вызывать ` pthread_cond_broadcast`.

Получается структура данных с одним `pthread_mutex_t lock`, одним `pthread_cond_t cond` и списком ожидающих потоков с их операциями и приоритетами.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант решения.

Читающие поток:

- лок на мьютекс;
- пока переменная не позволяет, ждем condition на этот мьютекс;
- выполняем свои секретные действия;
- делаем notify_one, чтобы отпустить кого-то из condition;
- анлочим мьютекс.

Пишущие потоки:

- устанавливаем значение атомарной переменной в блокирующее читающих;
- лочим мьютекс;
- устанавливаем значение атомарной переменной в не блокирующее (теперь оно не очень нужно);
- выполняем секретные пишущией действия;
- выполняем notify_one;
- анлочим мьютекс.

В такой схеме гарантированно пишущие будут иметь вытесняющий приоритет перед читающими.

Реализация:

```
template<typename T>
class SomethingDoing : public boost::noncopyable
{
private:
    typedef boost::mutex::scoped_lock scoped_lock;

    boost::mutex _mutex_data_access;
    boost::condition_variable _cond;

    atomic_bool _readaccess;

public:
    SomethingDoing ()
    {
        _readaccess = true;
    }

    void Write()
    {
        _readaccess = false;
        scoped_lock lock(_mutex_data_access);
        _readaccess = true;
        /*DO YOUR CODE HERE*/ 
        _cond.notify_one();
    }
    void Read()
    {
        scoped_lock lock(_mutex_data_access);
        while(!_readaccess)
        {
            _cond.wait(lock);
        }
        /*DO YOUR STUFF*/
        _cond.notify_one();
    }

};
```

UPD v2: (не могу писать комментарии больше) писателю и читателю требуется `_cond.notify_one();` в конце, чтобы отпустить ожидающих в condition читателей, если такие будут.

Comment: Может, для чего-то эта очередь и подойдет ТС.

--

Я имел в виду (когда говорил об очереди в своем комментарии) очередь, в которую *поток ставит себя*, а не кладет данные, которые заберет кто-то другой.

Понимаете? 

Add(op, mutex, mycond) -- это встать в очередь на выполнение захвата типа 'op' mutex-а. Поток просто перейдет в wait, если не может сразу сделать 'op`.

А вот Unlock(mutex) (через переданный в очередь `mycond`) разбудит нужный (по приоритету, соcтоянию очереди и mutex-а) поток (который ранее вызывал Add()).

Comment: @avp, я подправил ответ, удалив свою очередь, и просто на ее базе сделав то, что Вам нужно, насколько я понял задачу. Т.е. теперь это не очередь, а класс с двумя методами "читать" и "писать". Которые должны позволить делать и то, и другое, но с приоритетом у пишущих.

Comment: @smallFish, только это нужно не мне, а автору вопроса (@alglu65), и комментарий, скорее, для него, а не про Вашу программу.

Лучше не спешите, подождите *его* реакции (я-то ведь точно не знаю, что именно его устроит).

Comment: @smallFish: А зачем вам `_readaccess = false;` в начале `Write()`? Если его убрать, то доступ к `_readaccess` останется только под залоченным `_mutex_data_access`, а значит, можно превратить его из `atomic_bool` в просто `bool`.
____
@smallFish: Не, подождите, что-то я лажаю. У вас вроде `Reader`'ы выходят непараллельные, разве нет? Если один `Reader` находится в секции `/*DO YOUR STUFF*/`, то остальным приходится ждать, пока освободится `_mutex_data_access`.

Comment: @smallFish, что-то я не пойму, почему пожелание автора

     писатели имеют приоритет перед читателями

будет реализовано этим кодом?


IMHO код в 

     Write() { 
       ...
       _readaccess = true;
       ...
       _cond.notify_one();
     }

с равным успехом будет будить как читателей (что в `lock(_mutex_data_access);`, что в `_cond.wait(lock);`), так и писателей (в `lock(_mutex_data_access);`).

--

Может быть, boost ведет себя как-то иначе, чем pthreads?

Объясните.

Comment: @VladD, @avp, буду отвечать по порядку.
1. false в начале write нужен затем, что если у нас есть среди ожидающих потоков и читатели, и писатели, то любой писатель получит приоритет, т.к. установит для читателей false, подходя к lock, и читатели уйдут в сон, как только проснутся. Поэтому он должен быть atomic, его одновременно должны иметь возможность менять писатели и проверять читатели.

Comment: 2.И да, читатели у меня специально не параллельные, т.к. это условие автора. В противном случае ему подошел бы просто shared_mutex, но ему важно, чтобы и читатели - читали не параллельно, однако, ввиду их большого числа, и малого числа писателей, писатели бы при этом имели более высокий приоритет. И благодаря этому коду гарантированно, если и писатели и читатели ждут - "выходить" сначала будут писатели. Когда все писатели выйдут - только тогда читатели. Но при этом, как автор и хочет, и писатели, и читатели будут работать последовательно.

Comment: 3.Верно, cond.notify_one() разбудит и читателей, и писателей. Только если есть ожидающие писатели, то readaccess установлен в false, а значит читатели снова уткнуться в condition. Писатель же сможет писать. Так, собственно, и реализуется более высокий приоритет писателя, который будет писать всегда раньше читателей.
Однако, чтобы, если писатели могут занять весь эфир, они его не занимали, обратите внимание, что в случае, если два писателя ждут, и первый выйдет, установив readaccess в true, то второй писатель уже ждет без вытесняющего права. Т.е. "стопорения" не будет, а приоритет есть.

Comment: @smallFish: Ага, понял. Тогда я бы переименовал `_readaccess` в `_writerwaiting`. (Ну и поменял значения на противоположные.)

---
А зачем `Reader`'у `_cond.notify_one()` в конце? Его ведь всё равно никто не ждёт.

Comment: @smallFish, перечитал вопрос ТС. Да, пожалуй, Ваш код удовлетворяет запросам автора.

Иногда (гонки все же есть) читатель может опередить одного из писателей, но это, очевидно, не противоречит требованиям.

--

Этот вариант заставляет вставлять рабочий код читателя-писателя внутрь методов класса (или вызывать его из класса). Т.е. блокируются не данные, а код (что считается не очень правильным архитектурным решением).

Может, лучше сделать еще и вариант с раздельным захватом и освобождением блокировки?

--

Это мой последний коммент здесь... (limit, продолжить дискуссию не удастся).

Comment: @smallFish: Писателю-то да, а зачем читателю?

Comment: @smallFish: А, понял. У вас writer почему-то будит только одного reader'а (`notify_one` вместо `notify_all`), поэтому отработавшему reader'у приходится будить остальных. Правильнее было бы, вероятно, будить всех. (И пусть сражаются за `_mutex_data_access`.)

Answer (score 0):

Что-то не пойму, в чем проблема. Если потребители только читают данные, то обычных файловых блокировок достаточно. А если еще и изменяют (например, выбирают сообщение из очереди), то тут могут быть варианты. Какие именно - зависит от тонкостей задачи.

Цитатано тогда получится, что если на этом мутексе заблокируется читатель, и в этот момент придет писатель и начнет ждать уникальную блокировку, то вначале все равно отработает читатель, и только после того, как он освободит shared-блокировку, писатель сможет приступить к работе.
Логично. И в чем же тут проблема?